# Examine my argument that $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \not\equiv \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: logic, model-theory

**Setting**
Let $\mathcal{L} = \{+,0\}$. I want to show that $$\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \not\equiv \mathbb{Z}$$. Note $\equiv$ means elementary equivalence in this question.

**Updated Problem**

My issue is that given the four ring axioms for addition and identity:

$$ \forall x \forall y \forall z ~  (x + y) + z = x + (y + z)\\
 \forall x        x + 0 = 0 + x = x\\
 \forall x \exists y     x + y = y + x = 0\\
 \forall x \forall y     x + y = y + x$$

it seems like $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \not\equiv \mathbb{Z}$. As someone commented below if I can use multiplication then I may prove $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \not\equiv \mathbb{Z}$, but multiplication is not in $\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: That's a mess. $\mathbb Z$ does not "satisfy all field axioms." There are no multiplicative inverses. Second of all, it is possible for $(R,\cdot,+.0,1)$ to be different from $(S,\cdot,+,0,1)$ but $(R,+,0)$ and $(S,+,0)$ to be the same.

Comment: If you can use multiplication, then it is easy: consider the formula against divisors of zero $xy=0\implies (x=0\lor y=0)$. [Note that $+$ was not used here.]

Comment: For example, define $S=\mathbb Z$, $m\cdot_S n=0$ for all $m,n\in S$. Then $(S,\cdot_S,+,0,1)$ is different from $(\mathbb Z,\cdot, +,0,1)$, but $(S,+,0)$ is the same as $(\mathbb Z,+,0)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry for making such an elementary mistake in my proof. The confusion on my side still stands however, since doesn't the statement ℤ⊕ℤ≢ℤ depend on the choice of language? Is that what you were trying to show with S=ℤ, m⋅Sn=0, and (S,+,0) vs (ℤ,+,0)?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I removed the previously wrong proof and I am thinking of a new one pending some questions

Comment: Which is exactly what the question is about. You can't add a symbol not in the language in question. The other question is what you are using as the definition of $\equiv$. Do you mean isomorphism? Or do you mean that the set of statements in the language which are true for the left side are exactly the statements for the right side?

Comment: $\equiv$ is elementary equivalence. So I believe "set of statements in the language which are true for the left side are exactly the statements for the right side" is the correct interpretation.

Comment: @chibro2: the notion of elementary equivalence certainly does depend on the choice of language, but you stated what the language is in the first line of your question, didn't you?

Comment: @RobArthan palm face! So it's simply a matter of showing $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfy the ring axioms while $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ does not satisfy some ofthem

Comment: Technically, the symbol should be $\equiv_{\mathcal L}$, but we avoid such notation when the language is obvious, as it is here.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ahh I've seen that notation, now its pendantry makes a lot of sense

Comment: Why are you sure they are not elementarily equivalent? @chibro2

Comment: It's in the prompt. However under the language $\{+,0\}$ and axioms of associativity, 0 is idenity, additive inverse, and commutativity, it seems like they are elementarily equivalent

Comment: @ThomasAndrews to continue what I was saying, the ring axioms also should contain statements about multiplication, but $\cdot$ is not in $\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: There is nothing about axioms. You need to find a first order logic statement that is true for one, and not true for the other.

Comment: Maybe you realized that the answer of [Brian M. Scott in your latter question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1131204/53976) is in fact an answer of this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is [Brian Scott's sentence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1131204/7933), slightly simplified.

$$\forall x\forall y\exists z ((z+z=x)\lor (z+z=y)\lor (z+z=x+y))$$

This is true in $\mathbb Z$ - it essentially says that given $x,y$, at least one of $x,y,x+y$ is even.

It is not true for $\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$, for example if $x=(1,0),y=(0,1)$.

Answer (score -1):

I am not quite what the question is here. But I will answer the question

Show that there does not exist a bijective group homomorphism (isomorphism) between $Z$ and $Z \times Z.$

Note that every element of $Z$ can be written as $n.1$ or $-(n.1)$ where $n.$ means add $n$ copies of together and $-$ means take the additive inverse. i.e. $1$ generates the group.

$Z\times Z$ does not have this property for any element of it. If we take $(a,0)$ with $a \neq 0,$ as our
generator we never get non-zero in the second coordinate. If we take $(0,b)$ we never get it the first, If we take $(a,b)$ with both non-zero, we'll never zero in either apart from $(0,0).$

So no element generates.

Since the property of having a group element generate is defined purely in terms of the group actions, it would be preserved by an isomorophism. Hence no isomorphism exists.

(I discuss more of these sorts of arguments in my forthcoming book Proof Patterns. )

Comment: Your argument does not show that $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ are not elementarily equivalent (the first-order language of groups isn't expressive enough to talk about generating sets).

Comment: @RobArthan Yeah, unfortunately, the question did not make clear that elementary equivalence was what was being requested.

Comment: I think you accidentally the whole question ^^

Comment: As a general rule, when you are "not quite [sure] what the question is..." ask questions, don't jump into writing an answer.

Comment: There is a theorem stating that if some function $j : \mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathcal{N}$ is an isomorphism, then $\mathcal{M} \equiv \mathcal{N}$. However I am not absolutely sure if proving $j$ is *not* an isomorphism is sufficient to say $\mathcal{M} \not\equiv \mathcal{N}$

Comment: No, it is not sufficient @chibro2