# Isomorphism between direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, direct-sum

Given the language $\{+,0\}$, I would like to prove that $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is *not* isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, but I am not sure where to start?

Comment: As groups? one of them is cyclic...

Comment: apologize for the incomplete question, yes it's a group and I updated it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

HINT: Let $\varphi(x)$ be the formula $\exists y\,(y+y=x)$, and consider the sentence

$$\forall x\forall y\Big(\neg\varphi(x)\land\neg\varphi(y)\to\varphi(x+y)\Big)\;.$$

Comment: Just to make sure I am expanding your formula correctly, you're saying: $\forall x \forall y (\neg(\exists y ~ y + y = x) \wedge \neg(\exists y ~ y + y = y) \rightarrow \exists y(y + y = x + y))$ correct?

Comment: @chibro2: Not quite: you’re using $y$ for two different things. I think that you probably meant $$\forall x\forall y\Big(\neg\exists z(z+z=x)\land\neg\exists z(z+z=y)\to\exists z(z+z=x+y)\Big)\;,$$ which is correct.

Comment: May I ask how you were able to come up with this condition? is it well known given enough experience or through some act of creativity?

Comment: $\phi(x)$ means '$x$ is even number', intuitively.

Comment: @chibro2: The latter. I was thinking about the behavior of $\langle 0,1\rangle,\langle 1,0\rangle$, and $\langle 1,1\rangle$ as compared with the behavior of $1$ in $\Bbb Z$, hunting for something simple that would distinguish them. That led me somehow to consider the behavior of odd and even integers.

Comment: Better to use $z$ in the bound variable for $\phi$ just for clarity.

Comment: @Thomas: I understand the point of view, but I think it important for students to get used to the re-use of bound variables, at least in simple settings like this one.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott And, if you were the teacher in the room with the student, I'd agree with you, but you aren't there to help with the confusion.

Comment: This proves the stronger result that the two groups are not elementarily equivalent.

Comment: @André: So it does; I didn’t even think beyond the question. Thanks!

Comment: This method can be directly generalized to handle $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $\mathbb{Z}^m$ when $n <m$; here we have $n = 1$ and $m = 2$.  http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1160214/630