# Elementary equivalence of $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$

Tags: logic, model-theory

I have a question in model theory where I need to prove that $\mathbb{Z}^{n} \not\equiv \mathbb{Z}^{m}$ (= not elementarily equivalent) if $n\neq m$ in the language of groups $L = \{\circ ,^{-1},0 \}$.

I tried some sentences about generators but of course that FOL can't say something about basis... can someone help me?

Comment: Remember that $n$ and $m$ are fixed. Can you express "$x$ has order dividing $n$" as a formula?

Comment: But the order of each element in those group is infinity - they are torsion-free

Comment: Aha - you do mean $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and not $\mathbb{Z}_n$. One way to get started on these problems is to first prove (without counting generators) that the two groups are not isomorphic - that often involves some algebraic obstacle which can be expressed as a first-order sentence. For example, here is a proof for $\mathbb{Z}^1$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131193/isomorphism-between-direct-sum-of-mathbbz-and-mathbbz/1131204#1131204 . I will think about this one. In the meantime, could you add some context about where you encountered the problem? We look for that.

Comment: Do you mean in the language $L=\{+,-,0\}$? Otherwise, specify the interpretation of the symbols.

Comment: @Primo Petri: it must be that $\circ$ is the group operation, ${}^{-1}$ is inverse, and $0$ is the identity. That is common notation for the language of abelian groups.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idea I have is to look at the coordinates of each element after they are reduced modulo $2$, and ask about the set of odd coordinates.

As usual, say that an element $x$ is divisible by $2$ if $(\exists z)[z+z=x]$. Say that a set of elements $X = \{x_1, \ldots, x_k\}$ is *pairwise distinct modulo $2$* if no pairwise difference $x_i-x_j$ is divisible by $2$.

In $\mathbb{Z}^k$ we can find a set of $2^k-1$ elements that are not divisible by $2$ and are pairwise distinct modulo $2$, but not a set of $2^k$ such elements. These elements are in correspondence with the nonempty subsets of $k$ - the set tells which coordinates should be odd.

This answer is a direct generalization of [Isomorphism between direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131193/isomorphism-between-direct-sum-of-mathbbz-and-mathbbz/1131204#1131204) . We could also replace "difference" with "sum", so the groups in the question are not elementarily equivalent even in the language with only addition and equality.

I mentioned in a comment: one way to get started on these problems is to first prove (without counting generators) that the two groups are not isomorphic - that often involves some "algebraic obstacle" that can be expressed as a first-order sentence.  In this case, we have $\mathbb{Z}^n$ as a natural substructure of $\mathbb{Z}^m$ when $n < m$. So disproving the elementary equivalence amounts to showing that the Tarski-Vaught test fails (although that test is formally stronger, and asks about an elementary embedding).  Thus, if the groups are not elementarily equivalent, we expect that the algebraic obstacle will, as a matter of practice, be found as the counterexample formula for the Tarski-Vaught test.

Comment: "So disproving the elementary equivalence amounts to showing that the Tarski-Vaught test fails." Wouldn't this only show that $\Bbb Z^n$ is not an elementary substructure of $\Bbb Z^m$? It is possible to have $A\equiv B$, $A$ is a substructure of $B$, but $A$ is not an elementary substructure of $B$. For example $(\Bbb N \setminus \{0\}, \mathrm{succ})$ is a substructure of $(\Bbb N, \mathrm{succ})$, is elementarily equivalent to the latter, but the identity map is not an elementary embedding.

Comment: Yes, that is correct formally - my last paragraph is just trying to give some intuition. I rephrased things somewhat.

Comment: I see the spirit of the paragraph now, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that $n<m$.  Consider the first-order sentence that says "There are $n$ elements $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ such that, for every element $y$, one of the $2^n$ elements $z_j$ (explicitly written out in our first order sentence, since $n$ is fixed) obtained by adding some combination of the $x_i$ to $y$ can be written as $z_j = w \circ w$ for some $w$."  This sentence is true in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ but not $\mathbb{Z}^m$.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!